# Break up data into columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column and I want to create a query to have multiple columns.

For example, I have **test** column.

The data of this column looks like this:

```
record1 => **option1|value1;option2|value2**
record2 => **option3|value3**
record3 => **option3|value3;option1|value1;option2|value2;option4|value4**
```

The number of options and values are undefined.

I want to have this one test column break into number of option like this :

```
option1   option2   option3  option4
'value1'  'value2'  'value3'  
                    'value3'
'value1'  'value2'  'value3' 'value4'
```

my table like this :

```
    id  name    options
    1   name    age|12;color|red;active|yes;car|no
    2   name    age|15;member|yes
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't actually store the values as separate columns?

Comment: Is your question how to move data from one column in a table into multiple columns in that table, or is your question how to create a table with multiple columns? Also, can you share your table schema?

Comment: yes,my db defined like this.and it have lot's of entery.and the system programing for this method.

Comment: @NathanielFord : i want search a option value in this column.for example i want search option1=somevalue.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify much. When you say 'this' column, you should specify which column you mean. You also aren't answering whether you have legacy data you're trying to work with or you simply don't know how to set up a table with more columns.

Comment: @NathanielFord : i add my table above.and **this** is my options column and i have data to work with and i do not want to set up a table with more columns.tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom MySQL function called user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html) that can receive the variable name and the value to search for and then return the row or ID etc. as you need.

In that function, you will need to loop through all the rows in a read only cursor and use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the values separately and check for the match.

If you need further assistance then let me know.

For more info look into the MySQL manual for [string functions here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

An extract from a user comment from the above link that might help you write the function:
This will split an IP address ("a.b.c.d") into 4 respective octets:

```
SELECT
`ip` , 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 1 ) AS a,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1) AS b, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -2 ),'.',1) AS c,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -1 ) AS d
FROM log_table
```

Comment: tnx somnath.but i do not khow how many pieces that i have.in ip address we have 4 slice but in my table it may be 10 options and . . .