# mysql how to split a column into multiple columns with ambiguous number

Tags: mysql, split

Hello i want to split a resulting column in multiple columns just like on the link. But number of columns are not specific ;

**Example**

```
COL1                 |   OTHER COLUMNS
----------------------------------------
this,will,split      | some value
also,this            | some value
this,is,four,columns | some value
```

I want make this something like that ;

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4   | OTHER
----------------------------------------
this | will | split| NULL   | some value
also | this | NULL | NULL   | some value
this | is   | four | columns| some value
```

---

**edit**

it looks like similar that question but not:

[Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

I want results in 1 row, I dont want something like that;

```
RESULT
-----
this
will
split
...
```

---

on that question you can see there is specific number of cols. bu i dont. :(

[How to split a resulting column in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750584/how-to-split-a-resulting-column-in-multiple-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: my problem is split column, but it is not certain how many columns should be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create one relational table and add multiple entry in relational table, hear you don't need to think about column, you have to add entry in row.

eg.

```
Table 1:

ID | COL1                 |   OTHER COLUMNS
----------------------------------------
1  |this,will,split      | some value
2  |also,this            | some value
3  |this,is,four,columns | some value

Table2
ID | Table1_id | value
-------------------------
1  | 1         | this
2  | 1         | will
3  | 1         | split
4  | 2         | also
5  | 2         | this
6  | 3         | this
6  | 3         | is
6  | 3         | four
6  | 3         | columns
```

Please check this, i think fix your problem.

Comment: actually that  comes from relational table , I concat that rows into one row with "," first. it is something like , writer_1 , writer_2 , writer_3 ..... of a book. 
my writer-book table like   => writer_id - book_id.
even if I dont concat that table , how can I make this rows to column ?